# JS Global variable not recognized

Tags: node.js, json, actions-on-google

I set my variable as a global variable so google will be able to read the name the user enter in actions on google. in "agent.add", I added in what I want google to read out.

However, It just keeps reading as `your name is [object Oject]` instead of the given name. This is my code in my index.js.

```
var myName = {}; 

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

    function naming(agent){
        myName = agent.parameters.givenName;
        agent.add(`your name is ${myName}`);
    }
```

Comment: What do you receive when you do a `console.dir(myName)` before your `agent.add(....` statement?

Comment: Hi, @DavidR, it still prints out `your name is [object Oject]`

Comment: No, you need to open up your `DevTools` (Press F12 to open up) in your chrome and navigate to console and post what you see there.

Comment: It prints `[Object Object] `, this means it's accessible, Have you tried to stringify it? Try to use `agent.add(`your name is ${JSON.stringify(myName)}`);`.

Comment: And what's your `agent` data structure?

Comment: @DavidR it doesnt show anything. btw i'm doing it on the actions on google console.

Comment: @chŝdk Basically, IntentA allows user to give any name and google will response back the name given

Comment: @ALABADAMA can you try to write `agent.add(agent.parameters)` and see what it prints?

Comment: @chŝdk hi it works but how do I remove the `" "`. this is what it prints: 
`your name is "James".`

Comment: @ALABADAMA Well in that case it's correct, and there's no need to stringify it, just write `agent.add("your name is "+myName)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably shouldn't make that a global variable, particularly since you're just using it locally.

Something like this should work:

```
function naming(agent){
    let myName = agent.parameters.givenName;
    agent.add(`your name is ${myName}`);
}
```